# How to show the profile (user,super user,Admin) information based on the user type in dashboard page using angular Project

Tags: html, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In my angular application I have created the Dashboard page ,super user dashboard and admin dashboard pages. Super user and admin dashboard pages having the same data as dashboard page and some extra tables on it.That's why I have created the admin and components page as and some tables data in component.html page

And I have used the same navigation links(about,notifications,profile,logout) bar for all the dashboards which I have placed in basic Dashboard page.

Now I want to show the profile information based on the usertype(user,superuser,admin)when we click on the profile link.

I have created the page for profile link in navbar.something like:

**profile.component.html**

```
<h4>Username:</h4>
<h4>EmailId:</h4>
<h4>First name:</h4>
<h4>Last name:</h4>
<h4>Last login:</h4>
```

And I have called the user profile with GET method,I have got the details as

usertype,firstname,lastname,email-id,last-login details.

**Now I want to place the details of user or super user or admin details in profile page when we click on that profile link based on the usertype from the get method API.**

Navigation links in dashboard page:

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<nav>
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a routerLink="/dashboard" class="nav-link" id="col"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home fa-lg"></i>Home <span
              class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a routerLink="/About" class="nav-link" href="#" id="col"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg"></i> About</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a routerLink="/dashboard" class="nav-link" id="col"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bell"></i> Notifications&nbsp;<span class='badge badge-primary'>{{ncount}}</span></a>


      </ul>
      <div class="social-part">
        <a href="#" id="col" style="color: black;" >Profile</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <a href="#" id="col" style="color: black;" (click)="logout()">Logout</a>

      </div>
</nav>
```

I have tried many ways but not working Can anyone help me regarding this.

Comment: Create a `behaviourSubject` having current user type  on your service file and use it on your template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate section for each type of user profile, and check conditions.

**profile.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="userType == 'Super User'">
 // Super User profile section.
 <h4>Username:</h4>
  ...
 //etc     
</div>

<div *ngIf="userType == 'Admin'">
 // Admin profile section.
 <h4>Username:</h4>
  ...
 //etc     
</div>

<div *ngIf="userType == 'User'">
 // User profile section.
 <h4>Username:</h4>
  ...
 //etc     
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks@Viral Patel,I have One more doubt,I want to show the nav-link Report only for admin and super user.and not for user How can I show this based on condition.<li class="nav-item">
          <a routerLink="/Report" class="nav-link" href="#" id="col"><i class="fa fa-flag" ></i> Report</a>
        </li>

Comment: You can add: <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="userType != "User"><a routerLink="/Report" class="nav-link" href="#" id="col"><i class="fa fa-flag" ></i> Report</a> </li>